# Check which ward skins I own?

Tags: league-of-legends

I just received a ward skin in a capsule. It doesn't appear  in the loot panel. 
[image]

Is there any way to check which wards skins I own? Or I only can see them after locked my champ in the lobby before one game starts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Loot tab will only show you your ward skin shards, which you need to upgrade with orange essence to activate (click to enlarge):

[image: Ward skin shards.]

There's currently no place to see all your ward skins besides the lock in screen. The easiest way to look at them is to **create a custom *All Random* game**. This will give you one full minute to look at your ward skins; then you can simply quit:

[image: All random game type.]

Comment: You are correct but I have to say that you must not select aram because you can't ward in aram map thus you can't see your ward collection.

Comment: @EvelynnSpankers Thanks! It seems this must have changed recently.